# How to update content on page from a modal window using react-router-dom

Tags: javascript, reactjs

There is a modal window which added on page added by clicking on a spicial button and **completely** removed from the page by clicking on the close button. I tried to add a `<Link/>`  inside the modal window but it didn't work because i can't add a modal window component in main `<Switch/>`  in App.js(because modal window component is 'abstract'). I tried to use `withRouter`  but it only changed URL without updating a page. So how should i make a navigation ? I am only learning and making my first SPA for practice. So thanks in advance.

*app.js*

```
function App() {
    useEffect(main);

    return (
        <div className="wrapper">
            <Router>
                <Navbar/>
                <Switch>
                    <Route path="/:id" exact component={Category}></Route>
                    <Route path="/product/:id" exact component={Product}></Route>
                    <Route path="/booking/:uuid" component={Order}></Route> //the link shoul be to the Order component
                </Switch>
            </Router>
            <div className="footer black">
                footer
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

*problematic component where the link should be*

```
function CartBottomMenu(props){
    const storage = props.Storage; //does'not matter
    const price = cartCountPriceUpdate();  //does'not matter

    const OrderBtn = withRouter(({history})=> (
        <div className="checkout-btn" id="checkout">
            <div className="default-btn" onClick={()=> history.push('/booking/1')}>Оформить заказ</div>
        </div>
    ))

    useEffect(()=>document.body.querySelector('#total-price').innerHTML = price); //does'not matter

    return(
        <div className="cart-bottom-menu">
            <div className="total-price" id="final-cart-price">
                <span className="total-price-title">Итого:</span>
                <span className="total-price-span">{price}</span>
            </div>
            <Router> //this Router tag here just for pretty, i know it's not needed here
                <OrderBtn/> //the button with a link
            </Router>
        </div>
    )
}
```

modal window adds in document by this function passed to event handler.
At first it appends a "container" on the page then renders a Modal component inside it.

```
export function RenderModal(Modal, ...args){
    return function(){
        if(document.querySelector('#modal')) return;

        let modal = document.createElement('div');
        modal.classList.add(...args);
        modal.id = 'modal';
        document.body.append(modal);
        ReactDOM.render(<Modal/>, modal)
   }
}
```

something like this. CartModal is the modal main component.

```
document.body.querySelector('#cart').addEventListener('click', RenderModal(CartModal, 'modal-window'));
```

Сlicking the close button triggers funtion, which **completely** remove modal from page.

```
function closeModalWindow(window){
    window.parentNode.removeChild(window);
}
```

Maybe this is not the best way, but the only one that came to my mind

Comment: side not, Manipulating dom in react is not good practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's immediately clear that the additional router wrapping the nested component is hindering the linking-to from working with any outer `Router` component.

```
function CartBottomMenu(props){
    ...

    return(
        <div className="cart-bottom-menu">
            <div className="total-price" id="final-cart-price">
                <span className="total-price-title">Итого:</span>
                <span className="total-price-span">{price}</span>
            </div>
            <Router> // <-- this router
                <OrderBtn/> //the button with a link
            </Router>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Remove all nested `Router` components so the outermost one wrapping the app provides the same routing context to all components.

Also, instead of redeclaring the `OrderBtn` each render, just use the `useHistory` hook to gain access to the `history` object.

```
function CartBottomMenu(props) {
  const history = useHistory();

  ... // you say doesn't matter

  return(
    <div className="cart-bottom-menu">
      <div className="total-price" id="final-cart-price">
        <span className="total-price-title">Итого:</span>
        <span className="total-price-span">{price}</span>
      </div>
      <div className="checkout-btn" id="checkout">
        <div
          className="default-btn"
          onClick={()=> history.push('/booking/1')}
          role="button" // <-- don't forget appropriate aria role!!
        >
          Оформить заказ
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: But as I already wrote there is not any `<Router/>`  components around the modal component. There is only one main `<Router/>`  in App.js. `useHistory`  will not work without  `<Router/>`. And i know about unnecessary `<Router/>` . I just added it for let `withRouter`  work. Just for experiment.

Comment: @greg I don't follow. I looked at the code you provided, there's a `Router` wrapped right around the `OrderBtn` component that has the issue.

Comment: Sorry, i hadn't finished my comment before sent it. Just missclick.

Comment: Modal creates and deletes dynamically by button click. So i just cant add it inside main `<Router/>`. So i could not use `withRouter`  or `useHistory` inside it. Is there really no any other way?

Comment: @greg I see. It seems you've not provided enough context then. Can you update your question to include all relevant code? The modal code, where this `CartBottomMenu` component is rendered, etc...?